# can't execute trigger through hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, triggers

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
```

I have DATABASE trigger. But when I save object through hibernate session object, Its throws
above exception

Comment: Can you post the code you are executing and the mappings?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in hibernate 3.0.6.

Just follow the link for idea. If you post the code of yours can see..

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973262